# Java upgraded to version 17 still having issues with SonarScanner in Azure pipeline

Tags: java, .net, azure, msbuild, azure-pipelines

Recently we are having an issue with the Sonarscanner  in our .net project, the error indicated that we needed to upgrade the java from 11 to 17 which we did and set the envionment variables, but still it seems like it is picking up the older version not sure why. we are using Azure build pipelines and the sonarscanner is configured to run as part of build process. any suggestion why the sonarscanner not picking up the java 17 version or if i am missing sth here?

-- yaml file config that kick start the build and sonar process as below,

```
- job: xxxxxprocessorservicexxxx
  pool:
    name: Azure Pipelines
    demands:
      - Project -equals UTC
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  dependsOn: checkservicechanges
  condition: or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'), eq(variables['CreateAllServices'], 'true'), eq(dependencies.checkservicechanges.outputs['Myvariable.astridprocessorservice'], 'true'))
  steps:

    - task: JavaToolInstaller@0.189.0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '17'
        jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
        jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'
      env:
        JAVA_HOME: "$(JAVA_HOME_17_X64)"
        PATH: "$(JAVA_HOME_17_X64)/bin:$(PATH)"
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          cd /etc/bkupexec
          ./agent.be &
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          java -version
          whereis java
    - template: xxxxprocessorservicexxxx/xxxxservicexxx.yaml
```

-- The below is some relavent portion of the `xxxxservicexxx.yaml` template file

```
steps:

- bash: |

    set -xe # Fail the command if it exits with a non-zero value.
    java -version
    echo "$PATH"
    sudo dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner --version 6.0.0
    echo "2\$JAVA_HOME\:$JAVA_HOME" 
    sudo dotnet restore ${{ parameters.buildProjectFile }}
    sudo dotnet tool list --global
    if [ $(build.Reason) = 'PullRequest' ];
    then
      sudo /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-sonarscanner begin /o:"abcsoftware" \
      /k:${{ parameters.projectKey }} \
      /n:${{ parameters.projectName }} \
      /d:sonar.java.source=17 \
      /d:sonar.login=$SONAR_LOGIN_TOKEN \
      /d:sonar.host.url="https://sonarcloud.io" \
      /d:sonar.exclusions="**/Migrations/**" /d:sonar.verbose="true" \
      /d:sonar.pullrequest.provider=vsts \
      /d:sonar.pullrequest.key=$PR_KEY \
      /d:sonar.pullrequest.branch=${PR_BRANCH:11} \
      /d:sonar.pullrequest.base=${PR_BASE:11} \
      /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="**/*.opencover.xml" \
      /d:sonar.coverage.exclusions="**/obj/,**/bin/"

    elif [ $(Build.SourceBranchName) = 'master' ]
    then
      sudo /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-sonarscanner begin /o:"abcsoftware" \
      /k:${{ parameters.projectKey }} \
      /n:${{ parameters.projectName }} \
      /d:sonar.java.source=17 \
      /d:sonar.login=$SONAR_LOGIN_TOKEN \
      /d:sonar.host.url="https://sonarcloud.io" \
      /d:sonar.exclusions="**/Migrations/**" /d:sonar.verbose="true" \
      /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="**/*.opencover.xml" \
      /d:sonar.coverage.exclusions="**/obj/,**/bin/"

    else
      sudo /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-sonarscanner begin /o:"abcsoftware" \
      /k:${{ parameters.projectKey }} \
      /n:${{ parameters.projectName }} \
      /d:sonar.java.source=17 \
      /d:sonar.login=$SONAR_LOGIN_TOKEN \
      /d:sonar.host.url="https://sonarcloud.io" \
      /d:sonar.exclusions="**/Migrations/**" /d:sonar.verbose="true" \
      /d:sonar.branch.name=$CI_BRANCH \
      /d:sonar.branch.target=$CI_BRANCH \
      /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="**/*.opencover.xml" \
      /d:sonar.coverage.exclusions="**/obj/,**/bin/"
    fi
    sudo dotnet build ${{ parameters.buildProjectFile }} -c Release -o /app/build
    sudo dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" ${{ parameters.testProjectFile }} \
      -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=opencover
    sudo /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login=$SONAR_LOGIN_TOKEN
  env:
    PR_BRANCH: $(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)
    PR_BASE: $(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)
    PR_KEY: $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
    CI_BRANCH: $(Build.SourceBranchName)
    SONAR_LOGIN_TOKEN: $(SonarLoginToken)
    # JAVA_HOME: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64"
    # PATH: "$JAVA_HOME_17_X64/bin:$PATH"
  displayName: 'SonarCloud analysis and upload'
  failOnStderr: true
............................
```

-- The below error in the log indicate that it is stil using java 11, as its still complaining that it recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

```
16:02:42.7  Writing processing summary to /home/vsts/work/1/s/.sonarqube/out/ProjectInfo.log
Calling the SonarScanner CLI...
Executing file /root/.dotnet/tools/.store/dotnet-sonarscanner/6.0.0/dotnet-sonarscanner/6.0.0/tools/netcoreapp3.1/any/sonar-scanner-5.0.1.3006/bin/sonar-scanner
  Args: -Dsonar.scanAllFiles=true -Dproject.settings=/home/vsts/work/1/s/.sonarqube/out/sonar-project.properties --from=ScannerMSBuild/6.0 --debug <sensitive data removed>
  Working directory: /home/vsts/work/1/s
  Timeout (ms):-1
  Process id: 2085
##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk: available:28841.00MB out of 85160.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 6921MB, CPU: usage 7.85
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
Process returned exit code 1
The SonarScanner did not complete successfully
16:02:42.934  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

-- more logs   below,

```
2024-01-29T16:02:42.7037335Z ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2024-01-29T16:02:42.7038413Z 16:02:42.7  Writing processing summary to /home/vsts/work/1/s/.sonarqube/out/ProjectInfo.log
2024-01-29T16:02:42.7038632Z Calling the SonarScanner CLI...
2024-01-29T16:02:42.7197522Z Executing file /root/.dotnet/tools/.store/dotnet-sonarscanner/6.0.0/dotnet-sonarscanner/6.0.0/tools/netcoreapp3.1/any/sonar-scanner-5.0.1.3006/bin/sonar-scanner
2024-01-29T16:02:42.7198302Z   Args: -Dsonar.scanAllFiles=true -Dproject.settings=/home/vsts/work/1/s/.sonarqube/out/sonar-project.properties --from=ScannerMSBuild/6.0 --debug <sensitive data removed>
2024-01-29T16:02:42.7198592Z   Working directory: /home/vsts/work/1/s
2024-01-29T16:02:42.7198771Z   Timeout (ms):-1
2024-01-29T16:02:42.7199138Z   Process id: 2085
2024-01-29T16:02:42.7244526Z ##[debug]Agent running environment resource - Disk: available:28841.00MB out of 85160.00MB, Memory: used 20MB out of 6921MB, CPU: usage 7.85
2024-01-29T16:02:42.9298173Z Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main
2024-01-29T16:02:42.9305503Z    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
2024-01-29T16:02:42.9318777Z Process returned exit code 1
2024-01-29T16:02:42.9350161Z The SonarScanner did not complete successfully
2024-01-29T16:02:42.9352034Z 16:02:42.934  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
2024-01-29T16:02:42.9416577Z 
2024-01-29T16:02:42.9419588Z ##[debug]Exit code 1 received from tool '/usr/bin/bash'
2024-01-29T16:02:42.9423734Z ##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/usr/bin/bash'
2024-01-29T16:02:42.9464709Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
2024-01-29T16:02:42.9472247Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Bash exited with code '1'.
2024-01-29T16:02:42.9473270Z ##[error]Bash wrote one or more lines to the standard error stream.
2024-01-29T16:02:42.9473654Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Bash wrote one or more lines to the standard error stream.
2024-01-29T16:02:42.9517474Z ##[error]+ java -version

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9517801Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]+ java -version

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9518449Z ##[error]openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.9+9 (build 17.0.9+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.9+9 (build 17.0.9+9, mixed mode, sharing)

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9518971Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.9+9 (build 17.0.9+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.9+9 (build 17.0.9+9, mixed mode, sharing)

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9520000Z ##[error]+ echo /usr/lib/jvm/temurin-17-jdk-amd64/bin:/snap/bin:/home/vsts/.local/bin:/opt/pipx_bin:/home/vsts/.cargo/bin:/home/vsts/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/.ghcup/bin:/home/vsts/.dotnet/tools:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
+ sudo dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner --version 6.0.0

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9520826Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]+ echo /usr/lib/jvm/temurin-17-jdk-amd64/bin:/snap/bin:/home/vsts/.local/bin:/opt/pipx_bin:/home/vsts/.cargo/bin:/home/vsts/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/.ghcup/bin:/home/vsts/.dotnet/tools:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
+ sudo dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner --version 6.0.0

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9521651Z ##[error]+ echo '2$JAVA_HOME\:/usr/lib/jvm/temurin-17-jdk-amd64'
+ sudo dotnet restore astridprocessorservice/AstridApi/AstridApi.csproj

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9522104Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]+ echo '2$JAVA_HOME\:/usr/lib/jvm/temurin-17-jdk-amd64'
+ sudo dotnet restore astridprocessorservice/AstridApi/AstridApi.csproj

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9522602Z ##[error]+ sudo dotnet tool list --global

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9522907Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]+ sudo dotnet tool list --global

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9523429Z ##[error]+ '[' Manual = PullRequest ']'
+ '[' 110562-upgrade-sonarcloud-java-version-17 = master ']'

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9523823Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]+ '[' Manual = PullRequest ']'
+ '[' 110562-upgrade-sonarcloud-java-version-17 = master ']'

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9525164Z ##[error]+ sudo /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-sonarscanner begin /o:abcsoftware /k:utc-services-astrid-processor /n:utc-services-astrid-processor /d:sonar.java.source=17 /d:sonar.login=*** /d:sonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io '/d:sonar.exclusions=**/Migrations/**' /d:sonar.verbose=true /d:sonar.branch.name=110562-upgrade-sonarcloud-java-version-17 /d:sonar.branch.target=110562-upgrade-sonarcloud-java-version-17 '/d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=**/*.opencover.xml' '/d:sonar.coverage.exclusions=**/obj/,**/bin/'

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9526587Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]+ sudo /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-sonarscanner begin /o:abcsoftware /k:utc-services-astrid-processor /n:utc-services-astrid-processor /d:sonar.java.source=17 /d:sonar.login=*** /d:sonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io '/d:sonar.exclusions=**/Migrations/**' /d:sonar.verbose=true /d:sonar.branch.name=110562-upgrade-sonarcloud-java-version-17 /d:sonar.branch.target=110562-upgrade-sonarcloud-java-version-17 '/d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=**/*.opencover.xml' '/d:sonar.coverage.exclusions=**/obj/,**/bin/'

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9527604Z ##[error]+ sudo dotnet build astridprocessorservice/AstridApi/AstridApi.csproj -c Release -o /app/build

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9528027Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]+ sudo dotnet build astridprocessorservice/AstridApi/AstridApi.csproj -c Release -o /app/build

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9528782Z ##[error]+ sudo dotnet test '--collect:XPlat Code Coverage' astridprocessorservice/AstridApiUnitTests/AstridApiUnitTests.csproj -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=opencover

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9529416Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]+ sudo dotnet test '--collect:XPlat Code Coverage' astridprocessorservice/AstridApiUnitTests/AstridApiUnitTests.csproj -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=opencover

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9530099Z ##[error]+ sudo /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login=***

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9530523Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]+ sudo /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login=***

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9531065Z ##[error]Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9531476Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9532246Z ##[error]  java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9532872Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]  java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9533473Z ##[error]The SonarScanner did not complete successfully

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9533841Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]The SonarScanner did not complete successfully

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9534310Z ##[error]16:02:42.934  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9534667Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]16:02:42.934  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

2024-01-29T16:02:42.9535056Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2024-01-29T16:02:42.9559263Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;done=true;]
2024-01-29T16:02:42.9581006Z ##[section]Finishing: SonarCloud analysis and upload
```

Comment: Hi there, To isolate the cause of the issue, have you got a chance to check if it works in your **local** JAVA 17 environment for sonar-scanner-**5.0.1.3006** with your dotnet project?

Comment: JAVA_HOME and PATH as below seems to be correctly set, so not sure what is causing it      `+ echo /usr/lib/jvm/temurin-17-jdk-amd64`

Comment: `+ echo /usr/lib/jvm/temurin-17-jdk-amd64/bin:/snap/bin:/home/vsts/.local/bin:/opt/pipx_bin:/home/vsts/.cargo/bin:/home/vsts/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/.ghcup/bin:/home/vsts/.dotnet/tools:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin –`

Comment: its extracting from here and using dotnetcore3.1 wondered if that's the issue?
`Executing file /root/.dotnet/tools/.store/dotnet-sonarscanner/6.1.0/dotnet-sonarscanner/6.1.0/tools/netcoreapp3.1/any/sonar-scanner-5.0.1.3006/bin/sonar-scanner`

Comment: I also suspect that the tool was not installed properly, so I wonder how the project was built from the local environment. It may help isolate the cause of the issue.

Comment: I am a bit new to the yaml and pipelines, I can give a try locally but not sure how would I do it, as these are yaml files that are running in the azure devops, any recommendation?

Comment: Azure Pipelines are automation tool with the help which we can run a set of tasks on an agent machine. We need to make sure the workflow works in local environment and then proceed to test with pipelines. If there are differences between the local environment and agent machine, we can sort out ways to configure the environment. At the moment, we have limited information on your project and what environment is required. Besides, your workflow was defined in a template yml.